# JavaScript Linked List Causing Garbage Collection

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list, garbage-collection, ecmascript-6

I've implemented the following linked list data structure in JavaScript:

```
class Node {
  constructor(data, list) {
    this.data = data;
    this.list = list;
    this.prev = null;
    this.next = null;
  }

  remove() {
    if (this.prev) {
      this.prev.next = this.next;
    } else {
      this.list.start = this.next;
    }

    if (this.next) {
      this.next.prev = this.prev;
    } else {
      this.list.end = this.prev;
    }

    this.next = null;
    this.prev = null;
    this.list.length -= 1;
  }
}

class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.end = null;
    this.start = null;
    this.length = 0;
  }

  append(data) {
    const node = new Node(data, this);

    if (!this.start) {
      this.start = node;
    }

    if (this.end) {
      node.prev = this.end;
      this.end.next = node;
    }

    this.end = node;
    this.length += 1;

    return data;
  }

  remove() {
    if (this.end) {
      return this.end.remove();
    }
  }

  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    let current = this.start;
    while (current) {
      yield current;
      current = current.next;
    }
  }
}

module.exports = LinkedList;
```

I use it like so to update a list of animations:

```
static update(timeDelta) {
  for (let node of this.animations) {
    const animation = node.data;

    if (animation.animating) {
      animation.update(timeDelta);
    } else {
      node.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

The `node.remove()` line causes very noticeable lag in my game. I suspect it is triggering garbage collection. Perversely, if I comment out the `node.remove()` line and allow the linked list to grow forever, the game runs smoothly.

Animations are constantly being added and removed. I added some logging in the animation `update` function:

```
start iterating linked list
removing
ms elapsed:  0.45499999999992724
end iterating
start iterating linked list
removing
ms elapsed:  0.455000000000382
end iterating
start iterating linked list
removing
ms elapsed:  0.13000000000010914
end iterating
start iterating linked list
(13) updating
ms elapsed:  2.200000000000273
end iterating
```

You can see that the linked list is iterated many times per second with an occasional node being removed.

How can I achieve O(1) deletion from my list without actually causing a slowdown in performance?

Comment: What's the purpose of using a linked list? Can't you just use an array or an object?

Comment: I could use an array but I'm trying to avoid using `splice` which will have to shift all the elements over. I want constant-time removal of elements.

Comment: Then you can use an object.

Comment: Rather than dereference the data and thus causing GC hits. Place the object in another array and the use it for the next object you create assuming they hold the same data pattern and size. If not then you will just have to hold the data until there is a time when the GC hit wont effect the app.

Comment: @Gothdo do you mean that I should store these animations as key-value pairs in an object and then use the `delete` keyword on them?

@Blindman67 that's a good idea. So this linked list abstraction is pointless because of the GC?

Comment: No dont use delete.. Very bad for performance.

Comment: Any data that you dereference will incur a GC hit, it does not matter if its a linked list, array, or any other referance.. The rule is reuse or just keep until you can afford the GC hit.

Comment: You can also consider using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

Comment: Have a look at this. Not the same maybe but will give the idea of how to reuse. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/1640/performance-tips/14578/object-pools-for-short-lived-high-count-objects#t=201608201043209880215

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `node.remove()` line causes very noticeable lag in my game. I suspect it is triggering garbage collection.

Nope. The lag comes from the fact that every `update` call updates only very few animations.

Your problem is the old and famous "delete during iteration" problem. In your case, it doesn't trigger rare edge-case bugs, it simply stops the iteration:

```
while (current) {
  yield current;
  // after yielding, in the `update` function, we have
  //    node = current
  // and most importantly
  //    node.remove()
  // which assigns (with `this` being `node`)
  //    this.next = null;
  // then the iteration is resumed
  current = current.next;
}
```

Oops. The simple fix is to cache the next node to be iterated before yielding:

```
let next = this.start;
while (next) {
  const current = next;
  next = current.next;
  yield current;
}
```

(or something like that), but of course it still fails when the next node is deleted. A better approach might be to omit the lines

```
this.next = null;
this.prev = null;
```

from the `remove` method of the node, so that the references stay intact during deletion. This will not affect GC.

---

Another solution would be to drop the linked list altogether - it's overengineered unless you are frequently adding/removing nodes in the middle of the list *outside an iteration*. Filtering out old animations during an iteration is simply, it can be done with a good old (memory-efficient?) `Array`, even in-place:

```
function filter(array, callback) {
    var i=0, j=0;
    while (j < array.length) {
        if (callback(array[j]))
            array[i++] = array[j++];
        else
            array[i] = array[j++];
    }
    array.length = i;
}
function update(timeDelta) {
    filter(animations, animation => {
        var keep = animation.animating;
        if (keep) animation.update(timeDelta);
        return keep;
    });
}
```

(you might be able to optimise `filter` by not reassigning when `i===j`)

Comment: Ah, nice catch. I'm currently using your simple fix of caching the next node.